# Validate a jQuery-UI Spinner within a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-spinner

I'm using the "jQuery Validation Plugin" to validate the form fields.
It works very well.

I added a new field into the form. This field use a jQuery-UI Spinner, but I have no success to validate it.

This is th HTML code of the spinner element:

```
<form id="formAddCategory">
    <input id="spinTeamNumber" name="value" style="display: inline-block; margin: 10px; width: 3em;" size="3" maxlength="3">
</form>
```

This is the spinner code:

```
$("#spinTeamNumber").spinner({
    step : 1,
    min : 1,
    numberFormat : "n",
    alignment : 'vertical'
});
```

This is the validation code:

```
$("#formAddCategory").validate({
    rules : {
        "spinTeamNumber" : {
            required : true,
        }
    },
    messages : {
        "spinTeamNumber" : {
            required : "* Required"
        }
    }
});
```

[...]

```
if ($("#formAddCategory").valid()) {
    ...
}
```

But it does not work.
I also tried to define a custom validation method, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the `name`, **not** the `id`, of the input element within the `.validate()` method.

Your `name` is defined as `value`...

```
<input id="spinTeamNumber" name="value" ....
```

So you must use `value` within the `.validate()` method...

```
$("#formAddCategory").validate({
    rules : {
        value : {  // <-- the input NAME
            required : true,
        }
    },
    messages : {
        value : {  // <-- the input NAME
            required : "* Required"
        }
    }
});
```

To create the spinner, jQuery UI dynamically adds a container around the original input element, so you'll probably want to use the `errorPlacement` option to get the message to display on the outside.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6u18p6ju/**